# SwiftUI - Space between colored list items

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List in **NavigationView**. As per the design, each of its rows has a different color. They do not have seperator line, but instead there is a **4 points** between each of the rows. They are similar to the rows in this HTML code snippet.

```css
.max-w-414px {
  max-width: 414px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container max-w-414px mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 pr-0 mb-2 bg-primary rounded d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="bg-danger py-3 px-4 rounded text-light">Delete</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-12 py-4 mb-2 bg-primary rounded"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to have **onDelete** enabled on all of the rows. That is to say, I want to delete rows on Swipe-left gesture.

---

I have tried a lot. The closest that I have come to is to use a **Spacer().deleteDisabled(true)** between Each **NavigationLink**. But there is more than **4 points** space between the rows that I do not want.

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<20) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TaskView()) {
                        Text("List")
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.green)
                    Spacer(minLength:1)
                        .deleteDisabled(true)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    
                })
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50)
        }
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

#### How to build a List similar to the list in my HTML code snippet?

Comment: @Omid I do not want to have seperator line. I want to have 4 points space between each of the rows. It should look like the List? Have you run the code snippet?

Comment: did you try Spacer().frame(height:4)

Comment: @SimonePistecchia Yes. It has no effect.

Comment: to get just the view in HTML , you cannot use on delete. you have to make another custom cell with swipe gesture .

Answer (score 1):

is this similar?

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<20) { index in
                    
                        NavigationLink(destination: TaskView()) {
                            Text("List")
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 10, bottom: 2, trailing: 10))
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(4.0)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    
                })
            }
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50)
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get *close* with a List. The delete view looks a little weird with this solution, but maybe with some fiddling there's a way to fix that, too. First, get rid of the spacer entirely. Then, instead of using a solid color for your `listRowBackground` parameter, create a custom view and use it:

```swift
struct ListRowBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            Color.blue
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
        }
    }
}
```

Implement it like this:

```
.listRowBackground(ListRowBackground())
```